# Express validation error with express-validator

Tags: node.js, express

I want to use [express-validator](https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator) in my app.

Here is my **app.js** code:

```
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(expressValidator());
```

Below is my **route**:

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    app.post('/login', userController.login);
}
```

And here is my code for **login**:

```
exports.login = function(req, res, next) {
    req.assert('email', 'Email not valid').isEmail();

    var errors = req.validationErrors();

    if (errors) {
        return res.redirect('/login');
    }

    passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
        // do stuff
    })(req, res, next);
};
```

When I try to post something to /login I got the follwoing error message :

```
TypeError: Object # <IncomingMessage> has no method 'assert'
```

I saw that this might be related to an issue with app.use but right now i'm stuck...

**EDIT 1 :**
I change my app.use to those ones, but it doesn't solve my issue:

```
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(expressValidator());
app.use(app.router);
```

Comment: My bad... I imported my route file before app.use() so all the middleware were not taken into account !

Answer (score 1):

You should use `app.router` only after any middleware that you're going to use in your routes:

```
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(expressValidator());
app.use(app.router);
```

The reason is that the order in which you declare middleware with Express is very important: if you add `app.router` before `expressValidator`, it means, that the router middleware will get to handle requests before the validator middleware is even called and got a chance to add its magic to `req`.

Comment: I tried to put app.router at the end of my app.use but i still have the same error :(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue! your **app.js** and **route.js** code are just fine, but in your code for **login**, you have to change from:

```
req.assert('email', 'Email not valid').notEmpty();
```

and replace it for:

```
req.check('email', 'Email not valid').notEmpty();
```

If you see the code https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator/blob/master/lib/express_validator.js on line 198, **assert** is only an alias for **check**. And seems to have an issue with that name "assert", maybe confuses nodejs because there is a module called "assert", is only a guess. 
Anyway, seems to work just fine with it.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check by replacing **assert** with **checkBody**.

`req.checkBody('email', 'Email not valid').notEmpty().`

Do it like this.